# How is this statement from a TensorFlow implementation of a certain KL-divergence formula related to the corresponding formula?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, papers, implementation, kl-divergence

I am trying to understand a certain KL-divergence formula (which can be found on page 6 of the paper [Evidential Deep Learning to Quantify Classification Uncertainty](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2018/file/a981f2b708044d6fb4a71a1463242520-Paper.pdf)) and found [a TensorFlow implementation for it](https://github.com/aamini/evidential-deep-learning/blob/main/evidential_deep_learning/losses/discrete.py). I understand most parts of the formula and put colored frames around them. Unfortunately, there is one term in the implementation (underlined red) that I can't tell how it fits in the formula.

[image: tensorflow implementation of KL divergence]

Is this a mistake in the implementation? I don't understand how the red part is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should remain from a general code that has been refactored. By the way, the red code phrase is always zero. Because, `beta` is a vector of `1`, and $\log(\Gamma(1)) = \log(1) = 0$, i.e., `tf.math.lgamma(beta)`. So, sum of zeros will be zero.

As you said, the other parts of the code are clear and completely matched with the definition.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I was worried because I found this code multiple times on the internet, but it seems everyone copied from the same source.